# Can't restore encrypted backup created with 10.04's deja-dup on 14.04

Tags: password, backup, encryption, deja-dup

I ran a Deja-Dup backup on an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS machine. It was an older version of Deja-Dup that came with 10.04 LTS. I password protected it.

Then I installed 14.04.3 LTS Trusty Tahr from the 'Try first' and 'Install' CD on the drive, erasing and reformatting the drive. Installation was seamless.

Next I connected my external drive with the backup folder, and ran the 14.04.3 version of Deja-Dup. It asked me for my password. I entered it, and it will not continue. No error message. It just keeps coming back to the "Encryption Password Required" screen as though the password is incorrect. It's NOT incorrect. I cannot restore the data files I have backed up!

I know the password is correct because the dialog allows me to "show password", AND I used the same password for a backup of another drive from a different machine. The keyboard is functioning as it should.

My machine is a Dell Inspiron 1300 with 2GB ram and 1.73Ghz chip. The HDD is 40GB.

I think I might have lost all my data if I can't restore it!

What could've gone wrong and is there a way to break the encryption and restore my files?

Comment: Are you 200% sure that the password is correct? Could you accidentally have triggered NUM-Lock or CAPS-Lock while entering the password (either now or back when you created and encrypted the backup)? Is your keyboard layout correct? Did you try to enter the password into any text editor and copy/paste it from there, so that you see what gets typed and can be sure there's no mistake? Is your keyboard in good shape, no hanging keys etc?

Comment: I know it's correct because the dialog allows me to "show password",
AND I used the same password for  a backup of another drive from a different machine. The keyboard is functioning as it should.

Comment: Okay. I was just posting the general first few steps for when a password does not work. A notable percentage of similar questions would be solved already by that, but yours seems to be a tougher case. I'm not familiar with how deja-dup stores and encrypts its backups though...

Comment: While we're trying to furnish support, try to avoid using your computer in case you have to recover your data from your hard drive.  You may be able to regain a good hunk of it from livecd with testdisk and photorec and other recovery programs.  Depends if you did a complete wipe when you formatted or not.

Comment: Did you do a "test decrypt / read"  immediately after the backup was created? Maybe it never worked properly

Comment: @anonymous2: I did a wipe of the drive. What was there, underneath Ubuntu 14.04 is gone. 

Xen2050: No, I didn't do a "test decrypt / read" after I used the Deja-Dup on the 10.04 LTS.  I was unaware that could be done until you brought it up.  Must the "test decrypt / read" be done before exiting the Deja-Dup? Or do you do that from Terminal? I'm unfamiliar with it. 
Speculating "maybe it never worked properly" is not helpful. 
Thank you both for your replies, thus far. I do appreciate your attention.

Comment: @RickWhite This comment is likely to get overseen, please write that as answer below and accept it by clicking the check mark on its left afterwards. That's the way we mark questions as solved here. You can read more about how this system works on our little [tour] page. Anyway, nice that you got your data back. :)

Comment: Answer: 
I apologize to everyone here. I have solved my problem and answered my own question. It turns out, that I remembered the password INCORRECTLY! I was off by 2 characters. I swore I knew it; but in fact, I didn't. I discovered that I wrote it down and forgot where I wrote it down. I just found it last night. Again, my apologies to everyone here for wasting your time. You were right, @Byte Commander! Thank you for your help. I hereby mark this SOLVED. :-)